# Should I update my question or add an answer?

Tags: discussion, questions, editing, specific-question

I recently asked [this question](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/775/how-to-deal-with-a-dangerous-developmentally-disabled-person-i-can-not-avoid). I am now at a point where I would like to provide some feedback on the answers that were given.

Should I update my question with a UPDATE section? Or write my own answer? I tried meta for other SE sites (software engineering/ workplace), but apparently, this can differ per community. Are there already any preferred practices for this community?

Comment: Not a duplicate, as that question is about responding to a specific answer, while this question asks about what to do with a general update on the situation.

Comment: Hmm, this is difficult. There is, in my opinion, definitely some overlap with the question @Vylix mentioned (I want to describe what I tried and what worked or not), but I was indeed also thinking to include an update on the situation as it is now. I think I will accept that this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the update does not change the question so much that it invalidates most of the answers, it's okay to add a new section for the update.

You may have tried some of the suggestions and may want to provide feedback. If that's tied to a specific answer, you could consider leaving a comment on that answer. But if it's a general update, please update your question.

Of course, it's okay to self-answer as well, especially if your answer is different from the answers you've received. Keep in mind that it should be an actual *answer*, though.

---

*On a personal note, I'm curious to learn how you've fared.*